# What does jQuery .focus(1) do? How is it different from .focus()?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I saw `.focus(1)` in the jQuery UI code base and I could not figure out what the parameter is for.

How is it different from `.focus()`? 
I read `.focus` documentation on the jQuery website but am still clueless.

Thanks.

Comment: it does nothing, unless some other jQuery plugin or other js code extended it `.focus()`

Comment: Could you supply a link or show where `.focus(1)` is used in context?

Comment: I found this in jQuery UI's dialog.js https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js line 303

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`.focus(1)` it just means that you want 1 millisecond delay.

http://api.jqueryui.com/focus/

**API: *jqueryui***

```
.focus( delay [, callback ] )
```

> This plugin extends jQuery's built-in .focus() method. If jQuery UI is
>   not loaded, calling the .focus() method may not fail directly, as the
>   method still exists. However, the expected behavior will not occur.

Comment: interesting, looks like they overloaded it from: http://api.jquery.com/focus/ implementation.